# NullPointerException in put method of HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, put

I know its been asked many times before but I still cant understand my mistake..

This is just a normal code I am writing for counting the number of repetitions in an array( :) It might be a very long method for doing this, kindly suggest a smaller way also if you can think of)

```
public int find(int[] sequence)
{
    Arrays.sort(sequence);

    int temp=0,count=0,j=0;

    HashMap<Integer,Integer> data = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

        for(int i:sequence){
        Integer c = new Integer(count);

        Integer d = new Integer(j);

        if(i!=temp) {

        if(count!=0) data.put(c,d);
        count++;

        j=1;

        temp=i;


        }


        else j++;


        }

        count++;//This one causes the error
        //System.out.println(count);
        Integer c = new Integer(count);

        Integer d = new Integer(j);

        data.put(c,d);

            long ans =  TheSwapsDivTwo.factorial(sequence.length);



        for(int i=1;i<=data.size();i++){

                ans /=  TheSwapsDivTwo.factorial(data.get(i).intValue());
                System.out.println(data.get(i));
                }

                return (int)ans;

}

public static long factorial(int n) {
            long fact = 1; // this  will be the result
            for (long i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                fact *= i;
            }
            return fact;
}
```

The `put` method doesn't produce any errors in the `for` loop but it does for the implementation outside the loop.

Error is like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at TheSwapsDivTwo.find(TheSwapsDivTwo.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at com.topcoder.services.tester.java.TestProcess$Runner.run(TestProcess.java:386)
```

P.S. count++ caused the error... Foolish really.. loop was going out of bounds..

Comment: I doubt that you found correct line. First, `HashMap` allows null keys and values. Second, if exception is thrown by HashMap you'd see its methods in stack trace.

Comment: I didnt remove the null keys intentionally it was just a part of the code..

Comment: I can suggest a smaller way for factorial method...            public static long factorial(int n) {
  if(n==1)
   return 1;
  return n*factorial(n-1);
 }

Comment: @VKSingla Fair Enough :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line which should be giving NPE:

```
TheSwapsDivTwo.factorial(data.get(i).intValue());
```

i.e. `data.get(i)` is not present (`1<=i<=data`), either have a `null` check on each `get` value or make sure in your logic all `i` are present into map which you require to refer.

A test for putting null:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
m.put(null, null);
System.out.println(m);
```

It prints:

```
{null=null}
```

Comment: I really dont think that statement is causing the error, because when I remove the suspected put statement the error is gone..

Comment: something is missing then, what was the code at line:54 i.e.  TheSwapsDivTwo.find(TheSwapsDivTwo.java:54). Further putting `null` shouldn't give NPE else you would have that in stack trace. See my updated code

Answer (score 1):

If using a Map, try this

```
for (Item i : list)
   {
     Integer f = map.get(i);

     if (f == null)
         map.put(i, 1);
     else
         map.put(i, ++f);
   }
```

And then traverse the Map. Or else you can use **MultiSet** from [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

```
Multiset<Item> items = HashMultiset.create(sequence);
   System.out.println(items.count(someItem));
     for (Multiset.Entry<Item> entry : items.entrySet()) {
   System.out.println(entry.getElement() + " - " + entry.getCount() + " times");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `data.get(i)` returns null. It happens because you try to get non existing element (when `i = data.size()`)

Use:

```
for(int i=1;i<data.size();i++){
```

As the keys you put in `data` start from 1 to `data.size()-1`

BTW you should fix indentation and add {} after all if and else statements.